# Difference between member function and property

Tags: kotlin

What is the difference?

```
val isFinished: Boolean
        get() = actor.actions.size == 0
```

```
fun isFinished() = actor.actions.size == 0
```

I have no idea.

I expect them to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class Property**

Your first example is a class [property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#declaring-properties):

```
class MyClass {
    val isFinished: Boolean
        get() = actor.actions.size == 0
}
```

This property defines an (optional) explicit `get` method, often referred to as a "getter". You could also omit the getter and do:

```
class MyClass {
    val isFinished: Boolean = (actor.actions.size == 0) //parens not necessary
}
```

If omitted, as shown in the last example, the value will rather be a constant value which isn't re-calculated on each access. Both variants serve different use cases but in most cases, the latter will be sufficient.

Regardless, for a client of this class, the property can be accessed like this:

```
val mc = MyClass()
mc.isFinished
```

This shows accessing a property in Kotlin.

---

**Class member function**

Functions in Kotlin can also define functions, which can be referred to as member functions. Your second example demonstrates this feature:

```
class MyClass {
    fun isFinished() = actor.actions.size == 0
}
```

Defining a member function is similar to properties with explicit getters but still different for a client, since they have to *invoke a function* rather than accessing a property:

```
val mc = MyClass()
mc.isFinished()
```

*Side Note*

Note that the shown function utilizes an expression body which is equivalent to the following block body approach:

```
class MyClass {
   fun isFinished() { 
       return actor.actions.size == 0
   }
}
```

Learn more about functions [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 3):

The first statement defines a property and the second statement defines a method.
Assume you define both in a class `Foo`.

```
val foo = Foo()
if(foo.isFinished) {} // property

if(foo.isFinished()) {} // method - see () at invocation
```

Under the hood, both variants call a  function.

Comment: Right, they are different. But they do the exact same thing?

Comment: @Sandra Do they both give the same value? Yes. The difference is that one is a property and the other is a function. The property is the more Kotlin way to do things, I believe.

Comment: The two options give equivalent results, but of course they're called differently (with the property needing brackets, and the property none).  A property is the Kotlin way when it _behaves_ like a property: consistent, fast, with no visible side-effects.  A normal function would be more appropriate if e.g. it returned different values without a setter being called, or did some heavy processing, or made external calls.